# Ordenar por la columna fecha formato d M, Y con DataTables.js

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Estoy teniendo problemas para ordenar por la columna fecha usando el plugin DataTables.js

He seguido esta guía desde la web oficial: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

Añadido ambas librerías:

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/sorting/datetime-moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Y llamado a la función con el formato que uso:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('d M, Y');
$(".datatable").dataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtlpi',
    buttons: [
         'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    pageLength: 25,
    responsive: true
} );
```

Luego imprimo la fecha en el mismo formato y nada...

```
<?php echo date("d M, Y",strtotime($his->fields["returned_at"])); ?>
```

He probado modificando el formato y nada, tampoco ordena... ¿Alguien sabría como solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: EL plugin de Datatable viene con un filtro casi por defecto, donde puede buscar por cualquier dato que exista en la tabla

Comment: @JuanPablo Si, la libreria viene con filtros por defecto, pero el problema reside en los filtros por fechas, ya que usa el número de día pero no la fecha al completo para ordenar. Dejo aquí un gif de ejemplo: https://gyazo.com/71429ec7a7a1c0ee13619a7e9c56949b

Comment: ahh entiendo, yo los tengo y me los ordena pero estan en formato DD/MM/AAAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en que estas colocando mal el formato, te estas guiando por el formato de `PHP` y no es correcto ya que es diferente al formato de la librería `moment.js`

Formatos de la librería `moment.js`
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

En tu caso el formato que debes agregar es **'DD MMM, YYYY'**:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD MMM, YYYY');  
$(".datatable").dataTable( {
     dom: 'Bfrtlpi',
     buttons: [
           'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
     ],
     pageLength: 25,
     responsive: true
});
```

> El formato que agregues es sensible a minúsculas y mayúsculas.
>
> Los meses de las fechas se toman en ingles; para colocarlo en español,
>   debes usar `moment.locale()`

Ejemplo corriendo:
http://live.datatables.net/talaquki/1/edit

Comment: Perfecto! Lo he probado y ahora funciona correctamente! Muchas gracias...  Según leí en la guía tenía que poner el mismo formato de impresión que en el fn.dataTable, así que ahí estaba mi error...

Comment: (Perdona, se me olvido aplicar los puntos, creí que al darle el tick los aplicaba)

Answer (score 0):

Que tal  espero te sirva este ejemplo de  mi partelo realize de esta forma que es segun la opcion que escojan es la columna donde se filtra por el rango de fecha de que seleccionen en los inputs date, en cual a las columnas que donde filtro les coloque un tipo de dato para identificarlas.
 de esta forma

```
{data: 'RenewalDate', type:"text"},
 {data: 'SignupDate', type:"date"},
```

esto es donde  se realiza el filtro

```
 $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
           if ( $.inArray( settings.nTable.getAttribute('id'), allowFilter ) == -1 )
            {
               // if not table should be ignored
               return true;
            }

    var Range = $("#range").val();//escojo en que columna se filtrara

    var valid = true;
    var min = moment($("#txtMin").val());//Tomo los rangos de  la fecha
    var max = moment($("#txtMax").val());//tomo rango de fehca

    switch(Range){
      case "R":
        if (!min.isValid()) { 
          min = null; 
        }

        if (!max.isValid()) { 
          max = null; 
        }

        if (min === null && max === null) {
          valid = true;
        }
        else {
          $.each(settings.aoColumns, function (i, col) {
            if (col.type == "text") {
              var cDate = moment(data[i]);
              if (cDate.isValid()) {
                if (max !== null && max.isBefore(cDate)) {
                  valid = false;
                }
                if (min !== null && cDate.isBefore(min)) {
                  valid = false;
                }
              }
              else {
                valid = false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
        break;
        case "S":
        if (!min.isValid()) { 
          min = null; 
        }

        if (!max.isValid()) { 
          max = null; 
        }

        if (min === null && max === null) {
          valid = true;
        }
        else {
          $.each(settings.aoColumns, function (i, col) {
            if (col.type == "date") {
              var cDate = moment(data[i]);
              if (cDate.isValid()) {
                if (max !== null && max.isBefore(cDate)) {
                  valid = false;
                }
                if (min !== null && cDate.isBefore(min)) {
                  valid = false;
                }
              }
              else {
                valid = false;
              }
            }
          });
        }
        break;
    }

    return valid;
  }
);
```

y de esta forma es como ejecuto o corro el filtro

```
 $("#updatefilter, #updatefilterDonw").on('click', function () {
      $('#genealogy').DataTable().draw();
    });
```